# accessing a member of a struct variable from a function variable

Tags: c++, struct

I want to access a member of a variable through a function by giving it the variable name, I keep getting an error saying that a string doesn't have that member :L.
here is the struct.

```
struct questData {
int number;
std::string name;
std::string unlock;
std::string reward1;
std::string reward2;
std::string reward3;
int gold;
int xp;
bool completed;
std::string desc;
} qList [50];
```

then here is how i am trying to access the member.

```
void questGen(qNum)
{
    std::cout << "Quest completed - " << qNum.name << "\n";
```

and yes it is just a simple text adventure :(

Comment: i did have a parameter before hand i was just trying something different XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature is missing the parameter's type:

```
void questGen(questData qNum) {
    ....
```

Comment: i see that now, i originally had it as a string and it was throwing that error thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the variable you are passing to the function a data type declaration.  Remember that classes are just a way of creating your own data types like int (except classes can get a lot more complex).

```
void questGen(questData qNum)
{
    std::cout << "Quest completed - " << qNum.name << "\n";
```